# Completely remove hash from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how to take away the id from the url.
Like so:

Link to page:

`http://www.exampledomain.com/index.html#example`

When user click the link it becomes:

`http://www.exampledomain.com/index.html`

Comment: you might be able to do it with a redirect, but that's kind of kludgy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to this, depending on your specific context.

If you just want to remove the [hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) value:

```
    location.hash = '';
```

...but this leaves the `#` in the location. (It also scrolls the user to the top of the page.) To remove that:

```
    location = location.pathname;
```

...but this will reload the page, too. To solve all these problems:

```
    history.pushState({},'',location.pathname); 
    // back button returns to #example
```

or

```
    history.replaceState({},'',location.pathname); 
    // back button doesn't return to #example
```

...which [isn't supported in some old browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history) (including IE 9), but those are vanishing rapidly.

Comment: Very welcome. Don't forget to [accept answers to your favorite questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and in the future, try to [share what you've already tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you can.